# windows - both java 8 and 17 installed, does java -version always output 17?

Tags: java, maven

## Problem

I have both Java 8 and 17 installed, and I'm trying to use maven with Java 8 to run a `mvn clean package`

However whenever i run `java -version`, be it on powershell or on my IntelliJ terminal (with project structure set to jdk 8) it ALWAYS outputs

`java version "17.0.9" 2023-10-17 LTS`

`Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.9+11-LTS-201)`

`Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.9+11-LTS-201, mixed mode, sharing)`

## What i've tried

I've changed **JAVA_HOME** and **PATH** (both in the environment variables panel and temporarily on powershell) after and the java version remains the same but i do get the following line on `mvn -version`

`Java version: 1.8.0_202, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre`

and i've tried uninstalling Java 17 so only Java 8 remains, which just breaks java -version, it stops outputting anything at all

Does java 17 override java 8 on the `-version` command no matter what?

Comment: Try using the full path for both executables. They should be different.

Comment: Java 17 must still have been before Java 8 on your PATH.

Comment: Give yourself Powershell aliases of `j8` and `j17` that simply ensure the correct version is *first* in PATH

Comment: When you set JAVA_HOME maven will use that java to build your project. When you type `java -version` windows powershell will run the first java found on your PATH which is java 17.

Comment: @matt is correct. So my idea of an alias should work on `JAVA_HOME` first. It's actually very convenient to *pre*pend `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;` to `PATH`

Answer (score -1):

You have to change order on your PATH.
Java 17 must be before Java 8.

Comment: If you give the command to actually change the path this could be a useful answer, but right now it is pretty much just a comment.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).